# Is it possible to use my JSON data to automatically create HTML table fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a basic calculator that takes JSON data and factors in shipping/fees/tax etc and quickly tells me if it's worth buying.

I have manually, but successfully, created a table and everything works great! I am new to JQuery so this is pretty exciting to see it working.

My problem is, I created the table manually and my json data has over 70 items in it. And the number of items are always changing so I can't just make a template. I will show an example of my code:

```
<table> 
<tr> 
        <th>Good</th> 
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Profit</th>
        <th>Item Page</th> 
        <th>Buy Link</th> 
</tr> 


<tr> 
        <td align="center" id="good">data</td> 
        <td align="center" id="price">data</td>
        <td align="center" id="profit">data</td>
        <td align="center" id="item">data</td>
        <td align="center" id="buy">data</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
  var value = ((((data[0].rap * .9) - 375) * .9) / 100) * 6 - data[0].price
  var itempage = data[0].link
  var buylink = "http://shopping.com/" + data[0].shop + "/" + data[0].purchase_id
  var buyprice = data[0].price
  var worthit =  (value > 0) ? '<img style=width:10px; src="true.png">':'<img style=width:10px; src="false.png">';
  document.getElementById("profit").innerHTML = value.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("buy").innerHTML = ('<a href="' + buylink + '">Buy Item</a>');
  document.getElementById("item").innerHTML = ('<a href="' + itempage + '">Click Here</a>');
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = buyprice
  document.getElementById("good").innerHTML = worthit
});
```

```
[
  {
    "id": "2222720521",
    "link": "cheese.com",
    "rap": "53",
    "purchase_id": "s4PF4o",
    "price": "15.00",
  },
  {
    "id": "74891470",
    "link": "sausage.com",
    "rap": "12",
    "purchase_id": "oLeZpE",
    "price": "12.99",
  },
  {
    "id": "494291269",
    "link": "sauce.com",
    "rap": "12",
    "purchase_id": "BTwS5C",
    "price": "12.99",
  }
]
```

As you can see in my manual example I only used data from "data[0]". But my JSON has 70+ data objects.

Is it possible to automatically create the table rows with the data. I am honestly stumped and have no idea where to even start. Any help is so very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You can do a for loop on all your data for each object you create a new row and put the data in it. If you are using jquery you may want to use `$(selector).html(<value>)` instead of  `document.getElementById(<id>).innerHtml = <html> `

Comment: If you have more than one row of data, you need classes instead of IDs

Comment: What do you mean by number of items? Are the number of columns variable as will as the number of rows?

Comment: So sorry I forgot to add the JSON to my question, I edited the question.

Comment: @ Nico This sounds promising, unfortunately I am confused by what you are trying to explain. I am looking this up and hopefully get some understanding. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to loop over `data`, for instance with `.each` (since you use jQuery), or any of the native JS constructs (`.forEach`, `for ... of`).

For the rest it seems nicer to use jQuery to the full, using `$()` selectors and the `append` method, instead of using the `document` methods or HTML strings to create nested content.

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
  $.each(data, function () {
    var value = ((((this.rap * .9) - 375) * .9) / 100) * 6 - this.price;
    $("table").append($("<tr>").append(
      $("<td>").addClass("good").append(
        $("<img>").css({width: 10}).attr("src", (value>0)+".png")
      ),
      $("<td>").addClass("price").text(this.price),
      $("<td>").addClass("profit").text(value.toFixed(2)),
      $("<td>").addClass("item").append(
        $("<a>").attr("href", this.link).text("Click here")
      ),
      $("<td>").addClass("buy").append( 
        $("<a>").attr("href", "http://shopping.com/" + this.shop + "/" + this.purchase_id)
                .text("Buy item")
      )
    ));
  });
});
```

Note that you should remove the static HTML for the first row: all rows (except the header) are now created dynamically. This also means that you cannot use those `id` attributes. I have used `class` attributes instead since `id` values must be unique throughout your HTML document.

## Sorting

In comments you asked how you could sort the table by profit. Since profit is the result of some formula, I would first suggest to create a function for that calculation. Then use the `sort` method on the data with a comparator function (which returns how two items compare with regards to their profit), like follows:

```
function profit(elem) {
    return ((((elem.rap * .9) - 375) * .9) / 100) * 6 - elem.price;
}

function compareProfit(a, b) {
    return profit(a) - profit(b); // negative => a comes before b in order of profit
}

$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
  data.sort(compareProfit); // sort data items by profit
  $.each(data, function () {
    var value = profit(this);
    $("table").append($("<tr>").append(
      $("<td>").addClass("good").append(
        $("<img>").css({width: 10}).attr("src", (value>0)+".png")
      ),
      $("<td>").addClass("price").text(this.price),
      $("<td>").addClass("profit").text(value.toFixed(2)),
      $("<td>").addClass("item").append(
        $("<a>").attr("href", this.link).text("Click here")
      ),
      $("<td>").addClass("buy").append( 
        $("<a>").attr("href", "http://shopping.com/" + this.shop + "/" + this.purchase_id)
                .text("Buy item")
      )
    ));
  });
});
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed, I seriously cannot thank you enough. I noticed the 
 static table and edited it out. I had no idea this was possible. I prefer JQuery over JS and I am currently looking up .each. You rock

Comment: Do you know of a good way to sort the fields by this.profit? Is something like that possible?

Comment: You can apply the sort before the loop starts: `data.sort(function (a,b) { return a.profit - b.profit; })`. If you need the reverse order, then do `b.profit - a.profit` instead.

Comment: Oh wait, I notice that `profit` is not a field, but calculated. So then you must perform the calculation there for both `a` and `b` and then subtract. Something like `data.sort(function (a,b) { return ((((a.rap * .9) - 375) * .9) / 100) * 6 - a.price - (((((b.rap * .9) - 375) * .9) / 100) * 6 - b.price); })`. You could probably simplify that expression a bit, but this is the essence: subtract the values derived from a and from b.

Comment: Seems quite complicated. I think I may leave it for now as I am quite confused at the moment. I really appreciate the advice.

Comment: The comments section is not ideal for sharing code. So I added a section to my answer, breaking things down into pieces. Hopefully that clarifies it.

Comment: Got a night sleep and a clear head now. This looks great, I am understanding the 
 sort method you explained above and it is working! I changed the order so it sorts from most profit to least. I cannot thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Each loop in GetFunction

```js
var jsonData=[
  {
    "id": "2222720521",
    "link": "cheese.com",
    "rap": "53",
    "purchase_id": "s4PF4o",
    "price": "15.00",
  },
  {
    "id": "74891470",
    "link": "sausage.com",
    "rap": "12",
    "purchase_id": "oLeZpE",
    "price": "12.99",
  },
  {
    "id": "494291269",
    "link": "sauce.com",
    "rap": "12",
    "purchase_id": "BTwS5C",
    "price": "12.99",
  }
]
function renderJson(jsonData){
  jsonData.forEach(data=>{
    var value = ((((data.rap * .9) - 375) * .9) / 100) * 6 - data.price
    var itempage = data.link
    var buylink = "http://shopping.com/" + data.shop + "/" + data.purchase_id
    var buyprice = data.price
    var worthit =  (value > 0) ? '<img style=width:10px; src="true.png">':'<img style=width:10px; src="false.png">';

    var rowHtml=`<tr><td align="center" >${value}</td>`
    rowHtml+=`<td align="center" >${buyprice}</td>`
     rowHtml+=`<td align="center" >${worthit}</td>`
     rowHtml+=`<td align="center">${itempage}</td>`
     rowHtml+=`<td align="center" ><a href='${buylink}'>Buy</a></td>`
     rowHtml+=`</tr>`;

    $("#myTable tbody").append(rowHtml);
  });
}

renderJson(jsonData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" border=1> 
<tr> 
        <th>Good</th> 
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Profit</th>
        <th>Item Page</th> 
        <th>Buy Link</th> 
</tr> 

<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

> There is no `shop` Key in given Object so it will get undefinded

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the properties of the object to create your header then iterate the rows to generate the table.

```js
var sampleJason = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Bob",
    price: 1,
    something: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Barry",
    price: 20,
    something: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Bertha",
    price: 1,
    something: true
  }
]


var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

//Create thead
var thead = document.createElement("thead");
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
//Add the elements as headers
for (var prop in sampleJason[0]) {
  if (sampleJason[0].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = prop;
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }
}
thead.appendChild(tr);

frag.appendChild(thead);

//add a table body
var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
sampleJason.forEach(function(e, index) {
  tr = document.createElement("tr");
  for (var prop in e) {

    if (e.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      var td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = e[prop];
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }
})

frag.appendChild(tbody);

document.getElementById("dump").appendChild(frag);
```

```html
<table id="dump">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use templating engine, eg. [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) to generate HTML for you

data:

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
    data.map(function(item){
       var value = ((((item.rap * .9) - 375) * .9) / 100) * 6 - item.price;
       return {
         value : value,
         itempage : item.link,
         buylink : "http://shopping.com/" + item.shop + "/" + item.purchase_id,
         buyprice : item.price,
         worthit :  (value > 0) ? 'Yes':'No'
       }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<script id="table-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<table>
 <tr> 
  <th>Good</th> 
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Profit</th>
  <th>Item Page</th> 
  <th>Buy Link</th> 
 </tr> 
 {{#each items}}
 <tr>
    <td>{{value}}</td>
    <td><a href="{{buylink}}">Buy it!</a></td>
    <td><a href="{{itempage}}">Click here!</a></td>
    <td>{{buyprice}}</td>
    <td>{{worthit}}</td>
 </tr>
 {{/each}}
</table>
</script>
<div class="content-placeholder"></div>
```